# google chart arabic language fix in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

When using Google charts and inserting values using a foreach loop into the charts list, the displayed result from SQL Server in Arabic looks like this:

```
<script>
      
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});  
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Contry', 'Mhl'],
  @if (Model is not null)
    {
        @foreach (var data in Model)
        {

             @:['@data.Name', @data.Count],

        }
    }


]);

var options = {
  title:'World Wide Wine Production',
  is3D:false
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('myChart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

display like this:
ص&#x64…
ا&#x64…

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6qmr.png)

It should be displayed like this: `(['صنعاء', 2], ['الحديدة', 1])`